# Can you write a Facebook application in C?

Tags: c++, c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What API is available to use Facebook from C or C++, and is there a library to do the grunt work for me?  (So that you for instance can use Facebook from a desktop program written in C++.)

<sup><sup>Thanks [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe).</sup></sup>

Comment: If facebook exposes SOAP/REST API then you can write an application in any programming language.And AFAIK, Facbook does.

Comment: Yes I can. [I have a truly marvelous proof of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem)

Comment: Not sure why this question got a downvote, it seems a perfectly valid question with a straightforward answer

Comment: @TomJNowell: the question is not constructive at all. The only possible answer is "Yes" or "It depends on who you're asking/the programmer is". A more constructive question around the same topic would be more like "What API is available to use Facebook from C or C++, and is there a library to do the grunt work for me"?

Comment: @sehe then quite clearly there are people not in possession of your knowledge for which the answer is not so blatantly clear, and you could have just earnt yourself reputation with a the answer 'yes'.

Comment: Just because the only possible answer is yes, doesn't mean the asker is aware of this.

Comment: And I would have answered but Nicholas already did, no need to be rude about it. I think you've missed mine. It might be straightforward and obvious to us, but not to others, hence this questions existence

Comment: @TomJNowell:We expect an user to do some little research or put some effort on their problem before asking a Q.It necessary because it helps them frame better Q's which warranty's better responses.The OP showed no real effort really.Other than quoting the requirement/Assignment exactly as-is I see no real effort.The bottomline is asking a better Q helps people help you solve your problems sooner.Yes this qualify's as an Bad Question in my book because of reasons I explained and not because it is just an Question answerable by Yes or No.

Comment: @TomJNowell I don't think sehe means to be rude. He's just stating that this is a yes/no question. Rephrasing it to what he suggests opens it up for more constructive answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you are able to develop Facebook application using C/C++.

Here's a good API http://projects.seligstein.com/facebook/

Comment: That API's five years old, though. Does it still work against the current version?

Answer (score 3):

You can develop a Facebook Application in whatever language you want, as long as you can ask for data over the network.  The API does not care what language you are using to query it.  The SDKs are only there as a starting point for languages that are commonly used to write applications, such as JavaScript and PHP.

EDIT:
I know the question has already been "answered", but since the asker changed their question, here is information about repositories on github which may serve as starting points for modern Open Graph API C++ applications. All of these are open source :)

https://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=C%2B%2B&q=facebook&repo=&langOverride=&x=14&y=20&start_value=1

Answer (score 1):

sure you can my facebook Graph mobile app is developed using Qt c++

Comment: if it is open sourced qt project, do you mind sharing it here please?

Comment: not open source , but i can share  some piece of code .. get http://www.mobileborg.com/temp/src/facebookgraph.cpp and .h ...you cannot use it directly as a lot of classes are referenced but i hope it helps you to figure out how to in Qt ...

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing the code. i want it in pure ansi c++ but your code will help me a lot.